# Can anything be done with the cloth dropped by zombies?

Tags: minicraft

**Note that this question is about Minicraft (Notch's Ludum Dare entry).  NOT MineCraft.**

I've got tons of cloth but I'm unaware of any uses for it.  Can you do anything with the cloth that zombies drop?

Comment: Having the same problem.. and with cactus
had about 135 cloth and died with 1 gold sword with no armor Cloth must be something to be used 2 create armor but i dont know where the "craft thingy" is

Comment: @Mike it probably didn't get implemented due to the 48 hours of ludum dare being over... But Notch has announced a sequel, so that might include armor and stuff

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## No

[According to Notch himself](http://www.reddit.com/r/minicraft/comments/noaqt/what_is_the_use_of_cloth/c3at3gv), he was going to use it to make the pow glove, but then he decided against that for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I have 300 cloth and there is nothing that can be done with it.  I've looked all over various websites and have been unable to find anything.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing can be done with it: it's just there to mess up your inventory.